How are balances updated on Ethereum
Is there a program that upates the balance on an account and how is this information recorded on the state database?

Balances on Ethereum are updated through the execution of transactions by the EVM.
When a transaction is executed, it can result in changes to account balances, contract storage, and other state variables. These changes are recorded in the state database, which is a trie database that stores information about each account and contract on the Ethereum network.
The state database includes:

Account balances and nonces
Contract code and storage
Consensus-related data, such as staking deposits

The state database is stored by every Ethereum node, allowing for efficient verification and querying of the state at any given block.
You can read more about this in the docs of Ethereum Archive Node.
